# What's the best way to round a double or float in Scala?

Tags: scala, rounding-error

```
  // Purpose: Determine attendance based on ticket-price
  // Example: attendance(4.90) == 135
  def attendance: Double => Int = {
    (ticket_price: Double) => {
        120 + math.ceil(150 * (5.00 - ticket_price)).toInt
    }
  }                                               //> attendance: => Double => Int
  attendance(4.90)                                //> res0: Int = 135
  assert(attendance(4.90) == 135)
```

Basically the assert was blowing up and attendance was returning 134 instead of 135. So I threw math.ceil at it and it worked. But I was just wondering if that's the best/proper/idiomatic way to do it.

For those who wonder where this code came from: [attendance code](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-1.html#node_toc_node_sec_3.1)

Comment: It *depends* upon what is desired. Casting float/double to an integer type is a truncation operation. However, there are are many different variations, available, including actual rounding. Also, keep in mind that FP values can exhibit some odd edge-cases.

Comment: @user2864740 Well in this case, I expected 150 * .10 == 15. Not 14.998. So I guess it's to round to the proper number.

Comment: A couple of style questions: What do your constants (120, 150, 5.00) mean? I would rather see named values which indicate their purpose/meaning, if possible. Also, why are you returning an anonymous function from a method? It seems like an unnecessary level of indirection when you could have a simpler `def attendance(ticketPrice: Double) = 120 + math.ceil(150 * (5.00 - ticketPrice)).toInt` (note camel case and lack of extraneous braces).

Comment: @JohnLandahl I'm doing a problem from HtDP (in link above) in Scala. I'm using the Int => Int as the contract and assert as the test. Yes, you're right those literals should be in variables. But I was just doing a straight conversion from the book.

Comment: I'm not a scala expert, but to your comment "I expected 150 * .10 == 15. Not 14.998," if that's what you expected, then you should be working in a decimal-based number system rather than a binary-based number system (such as float and double). You cannot express 1/10 precisely in binary (just as you cannot express 1/3 precisely in decimal). Anytime you do floating-point math, you need to account for small rounding errors; you cannot safely compare two floating point numbers without checking for an acceptable delta. For decimal rounding, you need to use a library that supports decimal math.

Comment: @RobNapier That's the tricky thing. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: It depends on the numbers. 1/2 can be expressed finitely in both decimal and binary. 1/3 can be expressed finitely in neither. 1/10 can be expressed finitely in decimal, but not in binary. So for some numbers you will incur rounding problems and some you will not. That's why you must assume that rounding will happen and compare against some delta. Or, if you want things to round like decimal, you must do your math in decimal, and cannot use float or double.

Answer (score 6):

When working with money, you should not use float/double types. I know these ways:

1. Use integer numbers (i.e. Short, Int, Long etc.) with the smallest possible values (e.g. cents, satoshis, ...). This might be enhanced by value classes in Scala.
2. Use precise arithmetics like BigDecimal.
3. Use fixed point arithmetics with arbitrary precision. (This is basically the same with a).)

Note that you should be aware of integer overflows when working with money.